# How to call overloaded c# functions which the only difference is parameter passed by ref or not in c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++-cli, overloading, tracking-reference

I've a C# class library with overloaded methods, and one method has a ref parameter and the other has a value parameter. I can call these methods in C#, but I can't get it right in C++/CLI. It's seems compiler can't distinguish these two methods.

Here is my C# code

```
namespace test {
    public class test {
        public static void foo(int i)
        {
            i++;
        }
        public static void foo(ref int i)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

and my C++/CLI code

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int i=0;
    test::test::foo(i);     //error C2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function
    test::test::foo(%i);    //error C3071: operator '%' can only be applied to an instance of a ref class or a value-type
    int %r=i;
    test::test::foo(r);     //error C2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function
    Console::WriteLine(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I know in C++ I can't declare overload functions where the only difference in the function signature is that one takes an object and another takes reference to an object, but in C# I can.

Is this a feature supported in C# but not in C++/CLI? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Do you have a sane realworld example of when this could be required?

Comment: Did you tried it with a pointer instead of the variable?

Comment: Does this even build? if it does im intrigued too! +1

Comment: @cevik: I tried int *p=&i; test::test::foo(*p); also get error C2668

Comment: @Nicholas King: In c#, you can. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: @Jodrell: The C# library is not writen by me, and I don't have source code. The original function is  public bool StartJob(string TargetName, ref uint Object, int MajorCommand, int MinorCommand, byte[] InBuffer, out byte[] OutBuffer, out uint Result, int TimeOut)  and  public bool StartJob(string TargetName, uint Object, int MajorCommand, int MinorCommand, byte[] InBuffer, out byte[] OutBuffer, out uint Result, int TimeOut)

Comment: @czz wow you have taught me something new today and its only 9.55 thanks :-)

Comment: @czz +1 for question, `Object` is such a meaningful parameter name too ;-) Sorry I don't have the answer.

Comment: @czz You should edit the method signatures into your question formatted as code, they're not very readable this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could build a C# helper class that you use in C++/CLI

```
namespace test
{
    public class testHelper
    {
        public static void fooByVal(int i)
        {
            test.foo(i);
        }

        public static void fooByRef(ref int i)
        {
            test.foo(ref i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something helpful on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI#Tracking_references):

> C++/CLI uses a "**^%**" syntax to indicate a tracking reference to a handle. It is similar in concept to using "***&**" (reference to a pointer) in Standard C++.